# Time conversions not deterministic

Tags: c++, c++11, debian

I have written a program which should convert `iso 8601` strings into `std::chrono::system_clock::time_point`.
But it has sometimes an indeterministic behavior.
If you execute the program multiple times, the parsed timestamps differ by 1 hour.

As far as i know, when you want to convert date-strings(`iso 8601`) to `std::chrono::system_clock` types, you currently need some functions from ctime (this means, that you need to use c-functions), if you don't want to use external libraries.

So i used strptime(), mktime() and std::tm_t.

Here is the MWE:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main(void) {
    std::tm t;
    strptime("2016-01-01T00:00:00", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S", &t);
    auto time = mktime(&t);
    std::cout << "UNIX-seconds: " << time << std::endl;
    //std::cout << "tm-hours: " << t.tm_hour << ", UNIX-seconds: " << time << std::endl;
    auto tp = std::chrono::system_clock::from_time_t(time);
    {
        std::stringstream ss;
        std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(tp);
    }
}
```

If you compile it with  g++ --std=c++14 main.cpp -o out

and run it multiple times, I get one of the following 2 outputs:

```
UNIX-seconds: 1451599200
```

or

```
UNIX-seconds: 1451602800
```

But I currently don't know why I get sometimes the first and sometimes the second one.

If you uncomment the commented line, the indeterministic behavior goes away and I get the following line:

```
tm-hours: 0, UNIX-seconds: 1451602800
```

What can I do, to get deterministic behavior?

I have debian 8, g++v4.9 and my pc is in timezone Europe/Vienna.

Comment: Some of the C functionality is wrapped in [`std::get_time`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/get_time), if that's any easier for you to use. `strptime` and `mktime` aren't standard FWIW (just POSIX).

Comment: yes, I know, but std::get_time has the drawback, that it needs g++ v5.0 or higher, currently 4.9 is not supported...

Comment: Ah I forgot which version finally implemented it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mktime` respects `tm_isdst` member of `std::tm`. `strptime` does not change that flag and it retais its previous value. As `std::tm` is POD, `tm_isdst` is not initialized by default construction, so you need to initialize it manually, or you will get indeteminate value.

Comment: wow, thanks, that helped a lot.
But where did you get this information?
I can't find it in the manpages.